# gotoxy function with C ( linux/unix )

Tags: c, linux

I am making a terminal software like GNU MC and I need gotoxy foo, but it has to be in C. It can be in macro or in C, but not in ASM code because I don`t know ASM. Any bit operators can be used too, but I had no idea how to pseudocode it or how to start doing this. Any advice will be most appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the ncurses library for such a function

you need some function from the listed here

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/printw.html#PRINTWCLASS

Answer (score 17):

Hope this snippet works with you.

I found these snippet on google long ago. I just saved it on my disk, now after seeing your post I just opened it.

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
}

int main(void)
{
    gotoxy(10,10);
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting piece of code... definitely something you bookmarked for reason. Magical code for sure :)

Comment: working here too... experimenting with various parameters... strange foo indeed... it has something to do with the gcc I think... gotta debug that

Comment: read something about Esc-sequences -- the control codes for terminal emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Is this function sufficient?

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    printf("You are now at position (%d, %d). You"\
           " look around and you see a vast emptiness...", x, y);
}
```

You do, however, mention that you are using software like GNU MC (Midnight Commander?), so perhaps you actually mean something more like:

```
void goto_url(char* url) { ... code here... }
```

Comment: Not exactly... I think that the foo will need to have a return type as typedefed struct with both x and y positions... but the whole idea of the starting point  is missing for me here.... I am missing some stdin/stdout parsing stuff I think... well enybody who wishesh to start some small game with me doing that kind of software is welcome :)

Comment: Feel free to add that in version 2.

Comment: Yes, I may do so later... nGines first :)

Comment: I was actually trying to be sarcastic...  My point was that in programming, you *must* know what you want, and you *must* explain what you want when neccessary.