# how to move Cursor in c under Linux without using ncurses

Tags: c, linux, cursor

I wonder how to move Cursor in the console?

**For Example :**

```
gotoxy(int x , int y)
{ /*Put the Code Here*/ }
```

Comment: If your terminal is VT100 compatible, VT100 escape sequence (google it) is useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gotoxy function with C ( linux/unix )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581347/gotoxy-function-with-c-linux-unix)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gotoxy() implementation for Linux using printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683526/gotoxy-implementation-for-linux-using-printf)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
}
```

Also see: [gotoxy function with C ( linux/unix )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582245/5735775)