# update ascii grid printed to the screen without reprinting grid

Tags: c, animation, matrix

```
int main() {

    struct matrix m;

    m.rows = 20;
    m.columns = 20;

    m.grid = create_grid(m.rows,m.columns,'&');

    /* Example animation */
    printf("\033[H\033[2J");
    for (int i = 0; i < m.columns; i++) {
        update_matrix(m.grid,10,i,'x');

        if ( i > 0) {
            update_matrix(m.grid,10,i-1,'&');
        }
        printf("\033[H\033[2J");
        sleep(1);
        printMatrix(m.grid,m.rows,m.columns);
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        free(m.grid[i]);
    }
    free(m.grid);

    return 0;
}


void update_matrix(char** grid, int row,int column,char symbol) {
    grid[row][column] = symbol;
}

char** create_grid(int rows, int columns, char symbol) {

    int i,j;

    char **grid = malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        grid[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
           grid[i][j] = symbol;
        }
    }

    return grid;
}

void printMatrix(char** array, int rows, int columns) {

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            printf("%c",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
}
```

my method of animation is essentially to...

- print the matrix
- update the matrix
- pause
- clear the screen
- reprint the matrix

The problem with this method of animation is that it creates a flickering effect and i'm sure is very inefficient. What can I do so that I do not have to clear the screen and reprint the entire matrix each time.

I run linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from using ncurses, you could do

```
printf("\033%d;%df", row, column);
```

to set the cursor to the required row and column (note that in here, first row is `1` and *not* `0`) instead of

```
printf("\033[H\033[2J");
```

Print the matrix once after setting it up and then change the displayed matrix when modifications are made.

You might want to position the cursor to the first row and column before printing the initial matrix like

```
printf("\033[%d;%df", 1, 1);

m.grid = create_grid(m.rows,m.columns,'&');
printMatrix(m.grid, m.rows, m.columns);
/* Example animation */
for (int i = 0; i < m.columns; i++) {
    update_matrix(m.grid,10,i,'x');

    printf("%c[%d;%df", 0x1B, 10+1, i+1);
    printf("%c", 'x');

    if ( i > 0) {
        update_matrix(m.grid,10,i-1,'&');
        printf("%c[%d;%df", 0x1B, 10+1, i-1+1);
        printf("%c", '&');
    }
    sleep(1);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

`fflush(stdout);` may be needed to flush the output stream. Otherwise the changes written to `stdout` may not come on screen the moment they are changed.

But for such uses ncurses is better.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581347/gotoxy-function-with-c-linux-unix) and at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) wikipedia page as well.

Comment: my matrix code is obsolete. I can simply use `printf("\033%d;%df", row, column);` without the matrix

Comment: @cosine If you just need what is being printed out on the screen, I guess you won't need the matrix.